# coldfusion permissions on linux for file operations ( cffile, cfdirectory )

Tags: linux, coldfusion, permissions, file-permissions, user-permissions

I have a simple little admin system that works fine on IIS, but I'm having problems moving it over to Linux.

The system can create, rename and delete directories, create and upload/save files, and edit, rename or delete those files. On Linux I keep running into permission problems. The hosting company is solving the problem on a folder by folder basis, which isn't really a solution, because as soon as the system tries to create a new directory, it falls down.

I don't really understand Linux, but from reading it seems ColdFusion runs as a user, and that user has certain permissions given to it. What's the ideal setup for the ColdFusion user or solution on Linux, so I can do what I need to do to any folder/file under the root? For example, everything under `/home/mysite/public_html/`

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the user CF is running as to the group that owns the folder `/home/mysite/public_html/` and then set the permissions on the directory `/home/mysite/public_html/` to 775.

Comment: thanks, thats great, i will let the hosting company know. do you know if i'll need to use the mode attribute on cffile/cfdirectory, and is so would i also set that to 775?

Comment: Odd that a hosting company would not know that.

Comment: @DanBracuk they actually did work it out just before i was going to tell them - maybe they're reading this board! it did take them about 12 hours though!

Comment: @luke - No you will not need to use the mode attribute as it will automatically inherit the parent directories permissions.